# Why does a failed assertion trigger a promise catch?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, q

While writing unit tests for an angular app I was experiencing unexpected results.  I was able to condense the unexpected behavior into a sample test.

The `should.equal(true, false, 'should then')` assertion failure in the then block seems to trigger the catch block of the promise.

```
describe.only('test', function () {
  var $q, $rootScope;
  beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function(_$q_, _$rootScope_) {
      $q = _$q_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    });
  });


  var stubService = sinon.stub(service, 'getPanel');

  it('shall...', function() {
    //1
    $q.when().then(function() {
      console.log('log then')
      should.equal(true, false, 'should then') //<---assertion fails
    }).catch(function() {
      console.log('log catch') //<--- why does this block run?
      should.equal(true, false, 'should catch')
    })
    $rootScope.$apply(); //wait for promises to finish

  });
});
```

When I run this test the output is:

```
 LOG LOG: 'log then'
 LOG LOG: 'log catch'

  test
    ✗ shall...
  should catch: expected true to equal false
```

I expected:

```
LOG LOG: 'log then'

  test
    ✗ shall...
  should then: expected true to equal false
```

If I use this style I get the expected result:

```
$q.when().then(function() {
  console.log('log then')
  should.equal(true, false, 'should then')
}, function() {
  console.log('log catch')
  should.equal(true, false, 'should catch')
})
```

My company's convention is to use the first style so I would like to use the first style if possible.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation for the behaviour you're observing is that the `should.equal` assertion actually [throws an error](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/assertion.js#L141) underneath the hood when the condition isn't met.

Although you're using `$q`, I believe this [documentation on Promise behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) still applies, emphasis mine:

> The handler function (`onFulfilled` or `onRejected`) gets then called asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty). After the invocation of the handler function, if the handler function: ... **throws an error, the promise returned by then gets rejected with the thrown error as its value**;

So, in your case, the error thrown by `should.equal` causes the the code block for the `catch` to be execute, with the rejection value being the error thrown.